# How to run a group of PowerShell scripts in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, scripting, automation

I have a group of interdependent .ps1 scripts I want to run in Azure (trying to set up continuous deployment with git, Pester unit tests, etc., as outlined in [this blog](https://devblackops.io/building-a-simple-release-pipeline-in-powershell-using-psake-pester-and-psdeploy/)).  How can I run these scripts in azure without needing to manage a server on which those scripts can run?  E.g., can I put them in a storage account and execute them there, or do something similar?

Using an Azure automation account/runbook seems to be limited to a single script per runbook (granted, you can use modules, which is insufficient in my case).

Note that I need to use PowerShell version 5+ (I noticed Azure web apps and functions only have 4.x.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with Azure Functions.  However, given that you need v5+ of PowerShell, you may want to look at Azure Container Instances (ACI) instead.  It's a little different approach (via containers), but should not impose any limitations and will free you from having to manage a virtual machine.

Note: At this time ACI is in preview. Documentation is available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/).

There is a [PowerShell container image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/powershell/) available on Docker Hub that you could start with.  To execute multiple scripts in the container, you can override **CMD** in the docker file.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion!  Do you have any ideas for how to automatically manage container instances in ACI (I can't find sufficient powershell commands to use an automation account, and automation accounts don't seem to support Azure CLI yet)?  How do I deploy/tear down/interact with container instances without again resorting to a managed machine?

Comment: I've found ACI life cycle management to be possible through the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/ContainerGroups/CreateOrUpdate).